# Как вывести выбранные категории из таксономии в single (Нужны не все а именно выбранные) WP

Tags: php, worpdress

Я не могу понять как можно вывести именно выбранные категории. Допустим есть таксономия "Жанр" внутри заложены нужные мне категории допустим боевик, комедия. Как вывести выбранную категорию в single? get_terms выводит категории все что есть, get_term выводит только одну ,но там нужно указывать какую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я Вас верно понял, то можно использовать `get_the_terms()`, подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_the_terms)

Например, выведем ссылки на элементы таксономии 'your_tax', которые относятся к текущему к посту:

```
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'your_tax' );
if( is_array( $terms ) ) : ?>
  <ul>
    <?php foreach( $terms as $term ) : ?>
      <li>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term->term_id, $term->taxonomy ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $term->name ); ?></a>
      </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам! Я уже который час гуглю! Вы спасли меня!